# Read extern XML file with Spring

Tags: java, xml, spring

I want to be able to read a complex XML file which will be sent to me. This XML file is build on several XSD schemas. In the end some data will be stored in a database so I'd like to create a bean from this XML-file and save the bean to a database.
Document based database is not an option for me at this point.

Below you can see the structure of the file. Inside tag "command" is everything I need to extract and save to a bean. There is a lot of levels down the xml-tree so how do I do this fast and safe? There will be a lot of files coming in.

recievedXML.xml

```
<command>
    <documentCommand>
        <documentCommandHeader type="ADD">
        <!--Some stuff I don't need-->
        </documentCommandHeader>
        <documentCommandOperand>
            <catalogueItemNotification>
                <!--Some stuff I don't need-->
                <catalogueItem>
                    <tradeItem>
                        <tradeItemIdentification>
-->                         <gtin>Some text</gtin>
                        </tradeItemIdentification>
                        <tradeItemInformation>
                            <informationProviderOfTradeItem>
                                <informationProvider>
-->                                 <gln>Some text</gln>
                                </informationProvider>
-->                             <nameOfInformationProvider>Some text</nameOfInformationProvider>
                            </informationProviderOfTradeItem>
                            <targetMarketInformation>
                                <!--Some stuff I don't need-->
                            </targetMarketInformation>
                            <classificationCategoryCode>
                                <!--Some stuff I don't need-->
                            </classificationCategoryCode>
                            <tradeItemDescriptionInformation>
-->                             <brandName>Some Text</brandName>
                                <descriptionShort>
                                    <description>
                                        <language>
                                            <languageISOCode>xx</languageISOCode>
                                        </language>
                                        <shortText></shortText>
                                    </description>
                                </descriptionShort>
                                <functionalName>
                                    <description>
                                        <language>
                                            <languageISOCode>xx</languageISOCode>
                                        </language>
-->                                     <shortText>Some text</shortText>
                                    </description>
                                </functionalName>
-->                             <subBrand>Some Text</subBrand>
                                <isTradeItemAService></isTradeItemAService>
                            </tradeItemDescriptionInformation>
                            <tradingPartnerNeutralTradeItemInformation>
                                <tradeItemSizeDescription>
                                    <descriptiveSize>
                                        <language>
                                            <languageISOCode>xx</languageISOCode>
                                        </language>
-->                                     <shortText>Some Text</shortText>
                                    </descriptiveSize>
                                </tradeItemSizeDescription>
                            </tradingPartnerNeutralTradeItemInformation>
                        </tradeItemInformation>
                        <extension>
-->                         <!--More things I need but it is not present in all incomming files-->
                        </extension>
                    </tradeItem>
                </catalogueItem>
            </catalogueItemNotification>
        </documentCommandOperand>
    </documentCommand>
</command>
```

As you see some of the tags are the same, `<description>`-tag with its content tags are the same, some of them I want and some others I don't want.
I haven't really done this before so I could really need some help.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at jaxb: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/

Comment: Depending on the size you might want to use a document driven or streaming approach. If you have large (or many files) you might want to utilize Spring Batch to do the processing/reading (especially if the files are large you might want to use StAX to read and proces). If they are small just use JAXB to read and unmarshall the file and store the objects in the database.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have a similar problem, What do you men for large file? I have a xml file that is about 10Mb, in this case STax is better then Jaxb.

Comment: @M. Deinum The files are not very large but they are many.

Comment: @micha I'll look into the tutorial. Thank you!

Comment: I looked at JAXB but I don't understand how I should do this. The tutorial talks about schemas but I don't have any schemas I just get a file like the one above.
How do I map that file to a bean?
The file is about 15kB so it's not a large file, it's just many files.

Comment: According to your own text *This XML file is build on several XSD schemas*. To allow JAXB to do marshalling/unmarshalling you need those XSD to generate the classes to do the binding. If you don't have them you will need to create the JAXB mapping classes yourself or use something like `XmlBeans` or another XML mapping framework.

Comment: Sorry! @M. Deinum 
The thing is that the XML file has a lot of information that I don't need, there is about ten percent that I'm interested in so I'd rather not use the schemas. And the information I need is so far down in the file.
So you're saying that I need to map each of the twenty or so schemas to twenty or so java classes to read out and save maybe 25 values?
I've never done this before! And now I have 27000+ files to be saved in a database.
Do I need to map from the top or is it possible to start mapping at say <catalogue>-tag?

Comment: You can always use xpath to pull out what you need.

Comment: XPath did the trick!
Thanks @M.Deinum